# Got invalid certificate error trying to log in

Tags: bug, login, ssl, authentication

I got an invalid certificate error for stackauth.com a few minutes ago when trying to log in to SuperUser via Google. I tried again (after taking a screenshot and blacking out the potentially sensitive info in the URL) and it worked fine on the second try. I figured I should let you guys know anyway...

Here's the screenshot:

[image: certificate error for stackauth.com]

Comment: Is this on a work connection? My office VPN tries this on - and it fails horribly on sites with HSTS....